# How to assign a score to a player and accordingly add/remove points from their score during a player's turn

Tags: python

In this game I've been tasked to do, one part of it is where all players in the game start off with 0 points, and must work their way to achieve 100 points, which is earned through dice rolls. After player decides to stop rolling, each player's score is displayed. My problem is that I don't know how to individually assign each player a "Score" variable, in relation to how many players are playing initially, so for e.g.

Player 1: Rolls a 2 and a 5
Player 1 score = +25
and etc. for every other player

Essentially, I need help on how to check if for example user at the start inputs that 3 players are playing, 3 different variables will be assigned to each player that contains their scores, which will change as the game progresses.

I have no idea what the proper code should actually contain, hence why I'm looking for help

```
import random
playerList = []
count = 0
def rollTurn():
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    print("Your first dice rolled a: {}".format(dice1))
    print("Your second dice rolled a: {}".format(dice2))


print("-------------------------MAIN MENU-------------------------")
print("1. Play a game \n2. See the Rules \n3. Exit")
print("-------------------------MAIN MENU-------------------------")
userAsk = int(input("Enter number of choice"))
if userAsk == 1:
    userNun=int(input("Number of players?\n> "))
    while len(playerList) != userNun:
        userNames=input("Please input name of player number {}/{}\n> ".format(len(playerList)+1, userNun))
        playerList.append(userNames)
    random.shuffle(playerList)
    print("Randomizing list..:",playerList)
    print("It's your turn:" , random.choice(playerList))
    rollTurn()
    while count < 900000: 
         rollAgain=input("Would you like to roll again?")
         if rollAgain == "Yes":
             count = count + 1
             rollTurn()
         elif rollAgain == "No": 
             print("You decided to skip")
             break
```

I would like that during a player's turn, after rolling their dices, the value of those two rolled dices are added to that individual's score, and from there, a scoreboard will display showcasing all the players' in the lobby current scores, and will continue on to the next player, where the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a list for `playerList`, you should use a dict:

```
playerList = {}
playerList['my_name'] = {
    "score": 0
}
```

You can iterate on the keys in the dict if you need to get data. For example in Python3:

```
for player, obj in playerList.items():
    print(player, obj['score'])
```

And for adding data its a similar process:

```
playerList['my_name']['score'] = playerList['my_name']['score'] + 10
```